# Where are the training commas coming from in these radio butons?

Tags: javascript, html, css

For some reasons end of the options has a trailing comma. It's not in the template, I am not sure where its coming from.

At first I thought it was some script, but even after isolation the issue seems to persists.

```js
const options = [
        "Easy to use",
        "Loading",
        "Fast",
        "Others (Mention below)"
      ];
      const template = `
    <div class="question-title">sdjhaskjdhakjs</div>
    <div class="question-options">${options?.map((option, i) => {
      return `
      <div class="question-option">
        <input class="${"id"}-feedback-question-option" type="radio" id="${"id"}-${option}" name="option" value="${option}" ${
        options.length === i - 1 ? "checked" : ""
      } />
        <label for="${"id"}-${option}">${option}</label>
      </div>`;
    })}</div>
  `;
 
 document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = template;
```

```css
.question-title {
      position: relative;
      height: 40px;      
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      font-weight: normal;
      font-size: 16px;
    }

    .question-options {
      position: relative;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      font-weight: normal;
      font-size: 12px;
      gap: 10px;
      flex-warp: warp;
    }

    .question-option {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      gap: 5px;
    }

    .question-option>label {
      margin-bottom: unset;
    }

    input[type=radio]::after {
      content: '';
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arrays converted to string are automatically joined with `,`

Use `.join('')` to bypass this behaviour

```js
const options = [
  "Easy to use",
  "Loading",
  "Fast",
  "Others (Mention below)"
];
const template = `
    <div class="question-title">sdjhaskjdhakjs</div>
    <div class="question-options">${options?.map((option, i) => {
      return `
      <div class="question-option">
        <input class="${"id"}-feedback-question-option" type="radio" id="${"id"}-${option}" name="option" value="${option}" ${
        options.length === i - 1 ? "checked" : ""
      } />
        <label for="${"id"}-${option}">${option}</label>
      </div>`;
    }).join('')}</div>
  `;

document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = template;
```

```css
.question-title {
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.question-options {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 12px;
  gap: 10px;
  flex-warp: warp;
}

.question-option {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 5px;
}

.question-option>label {
  margin-bottom: unset;
}

input[type=radio]::after {
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: oh come on! 4 hours on this! thank you! thank you so much!